# Detect half-open websockets with PING/PONG

Tags: jetty, jetty-9

I'm using Jetty 9.2.24 as a WebSocket server. I want to detect half-open connections, so that no more messages are sent over this connection and buffered instead.

I know PING/PONG frames are used for this, so I tried sending PINGs periodically and set a low maxIdleTimeout. I modified my client to NOT return a PONG to see if Jetty would regard this as a failed connection since the RFC-6455 spec dictates that the remote endpoint MUST respond with a PONG. Apparently Jetty does not detect missing PONGs or I am doing something wrong.

What is the best way to continue. Should I implement the PING/PONG timeouts myself by explicitly receiving all PONG messages and detect a timeout? I would think this would be responsibility of the underlying websocket managing framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Note that [Jetty 9.2.x is EOL (End of Life)](https://www.eclipse.org/lists/jetty-announce/msg00116.html) you should consider upgrading.

Setting Max Idle Timeout and then causing the connection to not be idle by sending ping/pong isn't ideal.

The spec says that when you [receive a PING you must send a PONG](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-5.5.2), and Jetty indeed does that.

It does not say that [receiving a PONG](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-5.5.3), or not receiving a PONG, or receiving an unsolicited PONG has any meaning or behavior on it like you think it should.

Jetty 9.4 websocket will only keep a half-open connection open long enough to complete the current message (no matter how many frames it takes) then respond to the CLOSE frame it received (that caused the half-open connection).   So half-open is only for the duration of the active message, then CLOSED.  If no message is active, then the CLOSE happens immediately.

On Jetty 9.4 you can also add a `WebSocketFrameListener` and respond accordingly based on the frames received (eg: make the server end the conversation immediately, either via a CLOSE frame, or harsh disconnect)